# cambiar el class de <i> con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola deseo saber si puedo cambiar el class de `<i>` con jquery se que es con .attr pero nose como capturar el o seleccionar el `<i>`,
lo que quiero es que cuando le de click el class que efectivamente se que es un icono cambiarle por otro `class="fa fa-minus"` dejo mi codigo de mi boton.

**PERO CUANDO OTRA VEZ LE DEAN CLICK VUELA AL OTRO CLASS**

```
    <div onclick="detalle_venta(9)" class="text-center details-control">
<a><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$('#tabla_ventas tbody').on('click', 'div.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = tabla_ventas.row(tr);
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + 'Caja/traer_detalle',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {codigo: codigo},
            success: function (result) {
                if (row.child.isShown()) {

                    row.child.hide(result);
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } else {

                    row.child(result).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: puedes mostrar tambien el html para poder hacer un codigo ejecutable  con los snippets del editor?

Comment: Y lo puse con html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes poner la clase original en un atributo data para hacerlo más genérico:

```
<i data-original="fa fa-2x fa-plus-circle" class="fa fa-2x fa-plus-circle"></i>
```

Luego haces un simple toggle:

**JavaScript**

```
var i = this.querySelector('fa-plus-circle');
i.className = i.classList.contains('i') ? 'fa fa-minus' : i.getAttribute('data-original');
```

**jQuery**

```
var i = $(this).find('i');
i.attr('class', i.hasClass('fa-plus-circle') ? 'fa fa-minus' : i.attr('data-original'));
```

De esta manera te vale para cualquier clase(s).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, por ende marque como correcta espero recibir un voto a favor, Gracias

Comment: Ya está tu voto ;)

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores  _por ende marque como correcta espero recibir un voto a favor, Gracias_  ... Muy original. Sendos +1 de mi parte :) en la pregunta y en la respuesta.

Comment: No termino de comprender por qué seleccionas en jQuery, luego pasas a JS puro, luego de JS puro de nuevo a jQuery... ¿no sería mejor concentrarse en uno y hacerlo sin mezclar?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Es JavaScript, nada te impide usar jQuery con React, Vue u otro framework. Bien puede hacerse con `removeClass` o `toggleClass` y con condicionales, pero no lo veo necesario.

Comment: Lo que no termino de comprender es porque `i` lo pasas para que sea el objeto (haciendo `[0]`) y usar `className`, cuando lo podrías hacer directamente con jQuery y ahorrarte hacer dos nuevas selecciones del objeto con jQuery. Algo como `var i = $(this).find('i');
i.attr("class", i.hasClass('fa-plus-circle') ? 'fa fa-minus' : i.data('original'));`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro se puede perfectamente, pero me gusta ser semántico y prefiero usar `className` porque es justamente para este propósito. Puedes usar `attr` y lo que haya disponible, es cuestión de preferencia personal.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Sin embargo, estoy de acuerdo con tu punto. He actualizado mi respuesta para añadir ambas formas. Te agradezco tu observación.

Answer (score 2):

#### Puedes usar un doble `toggle`:

Se agrega la clase que no esté y se quita la que esté:

```js
$('i').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-minus').toggleClass('fa-plus');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<i class="fa fa-2x fa-plus"></i>
```

#### Si la clase a intercambiar está después de la clase inicial, basta con un solo toggle

No es necesario validar o hacer doble toggle si es que están en orden en el css, recuerden que los estilos de la última clase **declarada** sobreescribe los de las clases anteriores, por lo que basta con un `toggleClass` que agregue y quite la última clase en este caso el `fa-minus`.

> Nota: Para que esto funciona es muy importante que los estilos de la clase inicial estén antes que los de la clase que se va a agregar. en caso contrario, esto no funcionaría.

```js
$('i').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-minus');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<i class="fa fa-2x fa-plus"></i>
```

Comment: "_los estilos de la última clase sobreescriben los de las clases anteriores_" esto no es del todo correcto. En este caso funciona porque `fa-plus` aparece antes que `fa-minus` en el CSS de FontAwesome, y a igual especificidad, se aplica la última regla en la hoja de estilos. Pero si apareciese después, no funcionaría y se mostraría siempre el + (por ejemplo, si las clases fueran `fa-plus-square` y `fa-minus`, esta solución no funcionaría).

Comment: Cierto, cierto tienes toda la razón.. me crucé jaja.. los de la última clase declarada en el .css no en el atributo.

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro, ya edité.